# android ui only refresh once within handler

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I was doing a android APP of api22.

It has a service in charge of receiving message,and when it does,it tell the activity through basic handler,so the activity can refresh UI.

include:

1. change the button text
2. change if the button is clickable

I have tested:

1. every first time I open the APP,everything is fine.
2. Keeping the APP open,back the one activity to main activity,and then open that activity like the first time.
   Log told me,the msg service send is received by the activity, and debuger told me the code that refresh UI is executed,but still,not presented any change.
3. I have do the test lots of time,and it present the same.

so,what's wrong?What else can I do?

NOTICE:it works as service so I think all the binder thing is okay,and didn't post it.
There is only one problem until now is about the UI refreshing.

service code:

```
private void sendToken(String token,String ip,String port) {
    // zmq
    ZMQ.Socket mRequest = zcontext.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    // bind address

    mRequest.connect("tcp://"+ip+":"+port);

    // send data.
    Log.d(TAG, "token Connected! Sending data...");
    Log.d(TAG, "token tcp://"+ip+":"+port);

    mRequest.send(token, 0);
    Log.d(TAG, "token All data sent!");

    String tokenback = mRequest.recvStr();
    mRequest.close();
    Handler h = Unlock.handler;
    String strtokenback[] = tokenback.split(",");
    Log.d(TAG, "----"+strtokenback[0]+"---"+strtokenback[1]+"---"+tokenback);
    if(strtokenback[1].equals(token))
    {
        if(strtokenback[0].equals("Y"))
        {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "token yes");
            h.sendMessage(msg);

        }
        else
        {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 0;
            h.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

handler code:

```
Class Unlock{
public static MyHandler handler;

onCreate{
    handler = new MyHandler();
    btn_confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_unlockconfirm);

}

class MyHandler extends Handler {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            //成功
            iftokenright = true;
            btn_confirm.setText("确定");
            btn_confirm.setClickable(true);

            Toast.makeText(Unlock.this,
                    "SSSSSSS",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            trytimes = 5;
            //refresh();
        } else if(msg.what == 0) {
            if((trytimes--)>0)
            {
                String note = "错误的token，您还有"+String.valueOf(trytimes)+"次机会";
                Toast.makeText(Unlock.this,
                        note,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                iftokenright = false;
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                String note = "很抱歉,您总是输错token,我们建议5分钟后再尝试";
                Toast.makeText(Unlock.this,
                        note,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Unlock.this.finish();
                finish();
            }
        }
        if(msg.what == 2&&iftokenright==false)
        {
            String note = "当前网络不通，您还有"+String.valueOf(trytimes)+"次机会";
            Toast.makeText(Unlock.this,
                    note,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("sendmsg", "Gettttttthismsg2");
            finish();

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Which part of your code is causing problems, and would you be kind enough to post it?

Comment: thanx very much,I post it

Comment: In my way,I thought it kind of the thing that android don't allow change the button feature,that much time,because indeed the msg is received.

Comment: Where is this `MyHandler` being used / instantiated? You're referencing it here `Handler h = Unlock.handler;` but that's not where it's actually being instantiated.

Comment: I'm thinking you're not referencing the handler from the activity that's currently on the screen. But I can't be sure without seeing the part of the code i mentioned.

Comment: Or it will be something,beyond by level now,cause I am a beginner,and this APP is actually a tool not a product,I know I may be should go deep to it,but really need to solve it as fast as I can

Comment: where does the `btn_confirm` reference come from in `MyHandler` class?